# Is there a way to know about caller or user in TypeLoadException exception?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm getting this error:

> Could not load type 'X' from assembly 'Y'

The problem is that a lot of modules use that assembly and I don't know what module is the user of that type.

As much as I know about `TypeLoadException`, it only tells us what can not be loaded. It does not tell us **WHO** wants that type.

Can we somehow know about the **who** part?

**Update**

I'm using .NET 6

Comment: Isn't this something that the [Fusion Logging tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255669/107625) is helpful for?

Comment: @UweKeim, that question is for 13 years ago. I didn't read it first because I think 13 years means ages in the software development. Does we have Fusion for .NET Core 6?

Comment: You didn't specify the .NET version at all. Write more details, get better answers.

Comment: In .NET 6, the closest to the Fusion Logging I came across was [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing#how-do-i-debug-the-probing-properties-construction).